# Создать новую страницу в PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, пока осваиваю ларавель столкнулся с проблемой. Создаю новую страницу, прописываю роутинг в web.php файле, но при вводе localhost/users не переходит на новую страницу, а просто показывает основную. Причём, если я напишу разный набор букв после слеша, то всё равно возвращается основная страница. Ниже прикрепил код файла web.php[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <?php
Route::post('machine/export/', 'MachineController@export')->middleware('auth');

Route::post('choice/createOrder/', 'MachineController@createOrder');

Route::post('test', function () {
    return 'ок';
})->middleware('auth');


// Authentication Routes...
//Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
//Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
//Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
Route::get('logout', function () {
    Auth::logout();
    response()->redirectTo('/admin');
});

// Registration Routes...
//Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
//Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
/*Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');*/

Route::any('{reg}', function () {
    $settings = file_get_contents('build_settings.js');
    $settingsObject = json_decode($settings);
    if ($settingsObject->NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        try {
            $content = file_get_contents($settingsObject->publicPath . '/admin.html');
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $content = 'Фронт собран в дев режиме, однако приложение не запущено. Выполните "npm run serve"';
        }
        return $content;
    } else {
        return file_get_contents('admin.html');
    }
})->where(['reg' => 'admin/{0,1}.*']);//->middleware('auth');

Route::any('{all}', function () {
    $settings = file_get_contents('build_settings.js');
    $settingsObject = json_decode($settings);
    if ($settingsObject->NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        try {
            $content = file_get_contents($settingsObject->publicPath . '/index.html');
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $content = 'Фронт собран в дев режиме, однако приложение не запущено. Выполните "npm run serve"';
        }
        return $content;
    } else {
        return file_get_contents('index.html');
    }
})->where(['all' => '.*']);

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/login', [\App\Http\Controller\AuthController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');

Route::get('/users', function () {
    return view('users');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, кто изучил данный вопрос. Попробовал поковыряться и страница возвратилась после того, как указал путь до функции Route::any